# What does the word "Dreamworks" mean?

Tags: meaning

Ok don't take me wrong in this one. I'm asking because, I was asked to answer this question and I simply don't have a straightforward answer so please help me out.

What does DreamWorks mean?

I look in here https://www.espressoenglish.net/difference-between-job-work-and-career/  and it says you cannot use the word work in plural like saying *"I have three works to do this week." So that leads me to think a dream cannot have works ): I might sound stupid right there. But, I think it might have jobs instead.

Next the word DreamWorks leads me to think it means that dream works but I don't know if it works hard or it might be implying that dreaming works but IDK.

By the way, this DreamWorks word comes from the filming company DreamWorks SKG Pictures.

See this link: [Link](https://www.google.com.sv/search?q=dream+works&oq=dream+works&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.4780j0j4&client=ms-android-hms-tmobile-us&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)

P.S.
I would like to know if the phrase "Good work!" Is a valid expression as in "Good job!" I have the feeling I have seen or heard "Good work!" or "Good work done!" But that's just thought I dont really know.

Comment: I will give you a tip, not to discourage you from asking here, but as a helpful tool.  I do this a lot myself because sometimes I feel unsure of my memory of how something is expressed.  If I have a phrase that I think might not be the common way of expressing something, I put quotes around it in a google search, and then I throw an ordinary additional word into the search.  That last part is helpful because ...

Comment: ... otherwise Google assumes I am only interested in definitions, when actually, I am interested in blog posts, quotes from novels, forum discussions -- in short, authentic use of the language.  If the phrase with the quotation marks comes up a lot, and I feel good about the way it fits into the contexts, then I have my confirmation.

Comment: And yes, you can say "Good work!", "Excellent work, (name)!", etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know it was invented for the film company, it isn't a common English expression.

"Works" in English also means a factory, especially an industrial one, eg. "the 747 is built at Boeing's Seattle *works*".

So a film studio is a place where dreams are made, hence Dreamworks.

Comment: Well your answer works!

Comment: What about my second question though? Can you say "Good work!" To say "Good job!"?

Comment: "Good work!" and "Good job!" are both common expressions used to approve the manner in which a task or tasks have been performed. But while both can apply to a single task, it is also common to hear someone described as doing "good work" in general; that is to say, being a good worker.

Comment: @RonaldSole you really did answer my second question. Many thanks!